# Read a specific word properties value in java

Tags: java, file, properties

I have a properties file which contain a key and its value, in which its value is a string consist of many values:

```
transmit=[D-1]0.0 [D-2]0.0 [D-3]0.039236154

key=transmit

value=[D-1]0.0 [D-2]0.0 [D-3]0.039236154
```

It means that transmit is in `[D-1] Document 1` with value `0.0`, and in `[D-2] Document 2` with value `0.0`, and `[D-3] Document 3` with value `0.039236154`

My question is, how I can read the `[D-3]` and give its value as `0.039236154`?

Comment: share what you done.

Comment: nothing, because i don't have any idea @DilipKumar

Comment: thank you, but i still have no clue @BoristheSpider

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a code writing service. You show us _your_ attempts and we help you understand where you went wrong. You need to write _some_ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values for [D-1], [D-2], and so on you will first need to [read the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java) from the file.

If the line starts with using `string.startsWith(""transmit");` then you split the string using `string.split("=")`.  Split it by the equal sign because that is what splits the values and the word "transmit".

Splitting a string returns a String array and you will want to get index 1 (string.split("=")[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)) to get `[D-1]0.0 [D-2]0.0 [D-3]0.039236154`.  Note: Be sure that the split has a length of at least two to avoid an array out of bounds exception.

Now you have the string `[D-1]0.0 [D-2]0.0 [D-3]0.039236154`.  With this split it by spaces.  You can then loop through the array you got from the split and split each string by `\\]` to get the [D-1] and 0.0 separated. Note: You will use a double back slash before the bracket because the bracket is a reserved char in regex.

As you split the values you can put them into a hash map and have [D-x] as a key.

Here is the example code once it is read from the file:

```
String start = "transmit=[D-1]0.0 [D-2]0.0 [D-3]0.039236154";
start = start.split("=")[1];
String[] split = start.split(" ");
HashMap<String, Double> transmitValues = new HashMap<String, Double>();
for(String str : split){
    String[] s = str.split("\\]");
    transmitValues.put(s[0] + "]", Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above `value` i understood that your values are separated by `space`.

Following snippet will help you.

```
String[] tokens = transmit.split(" ");
Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[((\\w-\\d))\\]([\\d.]*)");
for (final String token : tokens) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(token);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        valueMap.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(3));
    }
}
// access values using valueMap.get("D-1")
```